# How to add jQuery validation to cloned sections?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, clone

In the original form section, the validation works fine, but the cloned form section doesn't have the validation.

When the original section has an error message, adding will give a new cloned form section but with a duplicated error message.

Making a cloned form section must not show up any error messages and it should validates its own fields only.

So how to add jQuery validation separately to cloned sections?

```js
/*
 jQuery validation: https://jqueryvalidation.org/
*/
$("#aform").validate({
  rules: {
    fullname: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    fullname: {
      required: "Please enter your Full Name."
    }
  }
});

function addval2() {
  $("#aform").validate({
    rules: {
      fullname_2: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      fullname_2: {
        required: "Please enter your Full Name.2"
      }
    }
  });
}

/*
 Code for cloning form section.
 Plugin repo: https://github.com/tristandenyer/Clone-section-of-form-using-jQuery
*/
$(function() {
  $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
    var num = $('.clonedInput').length, // Checks to see how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
      newNum = new Number(num + 1), // The numeric ID of the new input field being added, increasing by 1 each time
      newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone(false).attr('id', 'entry' + newNum).hide().fadeIn('slow'); // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value

    // New attributes (id, class, name) for cloned inputs   
    newElem.find('.fullname')
      .attr('id', 'fullname_' + newNum)
      .attr('class', 'fullname_' + newNum)
      .attr('name', 'fullname_' + newNum).val('');

    newElem.find('.error').remove();

    // Add validation for cloned sections.
    addval2();

    // Insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
    $('#entry' + num).after(newElem);

    // Enable the "remove" button. This only shows once you have a duplicated section.
    $('#btnDel').attr("style", "visibility: true");

    // Max form sections, including the original.
    if (newNum == 2)
      $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit"); // value here updates the text in the 'add' button when the limit is reached  
  });

  $('#btnDel').click(function() {
    var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
    // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
    $('#entry' + num).slideUp('slow', function() {
      $(this).remove();
      // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
      if (num - 1 === 1)
        $('#btnDel').attr("style", "visibility: hidden");
      // enable the "add" button
      $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "add section");
    });
    return false; // Removes the last section you added
  });

  // Enable the "add" button
  $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
  // Disable the "remove" button
  $('#btnDel').attr("style", "visibility: hidden");
});
```

```html
<h1>jQuery validation and cloning form sections</h1> 

<div id="entry1" class="clonedInput">
  <h2>Form</h2>
  <form id="aform" class="aform" name="aform" method="get">
    <div>
      <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
      <input id="fullname" class="fullname" name="fullname" minlength="2" required>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<p>
  <button type="button" id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" class="btn btn-info">add section</button>
  <button type="button" id="btnDel" name="btnDel" class="btn btn-danger">remove section above</button>
</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just a couple code comments: use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set `disabled`. It's odd, because you are setting `value` like that. Also, to set CSS styles, use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) rather than `attr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is that you create a second form with the id = "aform" and remember that an id should not be repeated, you can place the div id = "entry1" class = "clonedInput" inside the form so that the two fields created are inside Of a single form.

Try this

```
<h1>jQuery validation and cloning form sections</h1>    
<form id="aform" class="aform" name="aform" method="get">

<div id="entry1" class="clonedInput">   
<h2>Form</h2>
      <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
      <input id="fullname" class="fullname" name="fullname" minlength="2" required>
 </div>
</form>
<p>
<button type="button" id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" class="btn btn-info">add section</button>
<button type="button" id="btnDel" name="btnDel" class="btn btn-danger">remove section above</button>
</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script>

$("#aform").validate({
rules: {
fullname: {
  required: true
}
},
messages: {
fullname: {
  required: "Please enter your Full Name."
}
}
});

/*
Code for cloning form section.
Plugin repo: https://github.com/tristandenyer/Clone-section-of-form-using-jQuery
*/
$(function() {
  $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
    var num = $('.clonedInput').length, // Checks to see how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
    newNum = new Number(num + 1), // The numeric ID of the new input field being added, increasing by 1 each time
    newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone(false).attr('id', 'entry' + newNum).hide().fadeIn('slow'); // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value

   // New attributes (id, class, name) for cloned inputs            
   newElem.find('.fullname')
  .attr('id', 'fullname_' + newNum)
  .attr('class', 'fullname_' + newNum)
  .attr('name', 'fullname_' + newNum).val('');

   newElem.find('.error').remove();


// Insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
$('#entry' + num).after(newElem);

// Enable the "remove" button. This only shows once you have a duplicated section.
$('#btnDel').attr("style", "visibility: true");

// Max form sections, including the original.
if (newNum == 2)
     $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit"); // value here updates the text in the 'add' button when the limit is reached  
 });

 $('#btnDel').click(function() {
    var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
    // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
    $('#entry' + num).slideUp('slow', function() {
      $(this).remove();
      // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
     if (num - 1 === 1)
       $('#btnDel').attr("style", "visibility: hidden");
      // enable the "add" button
      $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "add section");
    });
    return false; // Removes the last section you added
  });

 // Enable the "add" button
 $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
 // Disable the "remove" button
 $('#btnDel').attr("style", "visibility: hidden");
});

</script>
```

Comment: In the cloned Full name input, when i typed something and then erase it. Instead of getting the message "Please enter your Full Name.", I get "This field is required.".

Comment: Ok, I hope I help you.